# e possivel utilizar wilcard no firebase hosting?

Tags: firebase

tenho um site hospedado no hosting do firebase, e queria que ele respondesse a qualquer pedido de subdominio, como um wilcard dns, por exemplo:

se eu acessar
https://moreirasbuffet.com ou
https://teste.moreirasbuffet.com ou
https://vendas.moreirasbuffet.com ou
https://clientes.moreirasbuffet.com ou
https://*.moreirasbuffet.com

o cliente recebe a mesma pagina como resposta.

e possivel??

obs: não quero e nao posso criar cada subdominio manualmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como mostra [a documentação](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites?hl=pt-pt), o Firebase Hosting pode fazer [redirecionamentos](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites?hl=pt-pt#section-redirects). Mas estes redirecionamentos só funcionam na URL (e não em subdomínios como você precisa). Por exemplo, você poderia redirecionar https://moreirasbuffet.com/* para a página https://moreirasbuffet.com/index.html apenas editando o seu ficheiro `firebase.json` para colocar:

```
"hosting": {
  // Add the "redirects" section within "hosting"
  "redirects": [ {
    "source" : "/*",
    "destination" : "https://moreirasbuffet.com/index.html",
    "type" : 301
  } ]
}
```

Infelizmente, essa funcionalidade não está disponível para subdomínios, porque o Firebase espera que você crie eles manualmente (coisa que você disse que não quer nem pode).